# LISP find last paired parenthesys

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

The function i wrote has to return the position of the } corresponding to the first occurrence of the { it finds from the start (i'm not looking for the last occurrence of }).
For example, given this JSON-kind structured string

`(paired-b (coerce "[{\"b\" : {\"c\" : [[1, {\"d\" : 1}] , {\"e\" : 3}]}, \"g\" : 2}, {\"a\" : 2}]" 'list)`

the function should 
return the } (paired to the first { of the string) that is before the subsequence -> , {\"a\" : 2} ", but instead return the position the one before the subsequence -> , \"g\" : 2} ...
But if i try with

```
(paired-b (coerce "[ {\"a\" : 1} , {\"b\" : 2} ]" 'list))
```

the function return the correct position of the wanted }, the one before the comma.
Which part of the code is bugged? Is there another way to implement a function like this?

```
(defun paired-b (list)
  (if (position #\{ list)
      (if (< (position #\{ list) (position #\} list))
          (if (eql (position #\{ list) (- (position #\} list) 1))
              (position #\} list :start
                        (+ (position #\{ list)
                           (paired-b (subseq list (+ (position #\{ list) 1))) 1))
            (position #\} list :start
                      (+ (position #\{ list)
                         (paired-b (subseq list (+ (position #\{ list) 1) 2))))) 0) 0))
```

EDIT: I tried with something totally different

```
(defun return-c (input open close pos)
  (if (and (eql open close) (not (and (eql 0 open) (eql 0 close))))
      (- pos 1)
    (cond ((eql (car input) #\{)
           (return-c (cdr input) (+ 1 open) close (+ 1 pos)))
          ((eql (car input) #\})
           (return-c (cdr input) open (+ 1 close) (+ 1 pos)))
          (t (return-c (cdr input) open close (+ 1 pos))) 
          )
    )
  )
```

open =  count {, close = count }, pos = position od index

This code seems to work, but inside the parser, with others functions calling it, if i parse long strings the program goes stackoverflow.

Comment: `(not (null ...))` is `...`

Comment: Numbers are compared with `eql` or `=`, but not with `eq`.

Comment: Multiple times `(position #\somechar x)` is ugly.

Comment: write `(eql (...` and not `(eql(`.

Comment: don't use dangling parentheses.

Comment: I would also improve naming of variables. `x` says nothing.

Comment: Then think about formatting your code.

Comment: I will edit the code as soon as possible, thank you.

Comment: Edited as you suggest.

Comment: So with some work you might eventually get this to work but: Coercing a vector (string) to a list and using that will rubbish your performance—you can use `loop` with `for-across` or just `aref` instead. Also be careful what you want to do about malformed input. Also look out for e.g. `{` in strings (and `\"`). If your end goal is to parse I would recommend using/modifying a library or using a stream (e.g. `with-input-from-string`) and just writing an entire parser examining one character at a time.

Comment: The fact is that the function i'm looking for is part of a parser from JSON-string to a LISP-list equivalent, and in a certain case i need this kind of function to find the type of } occurrence.Also, one of the aim of this project is not to use LOOP or other kind of iterations, just recursive functions. I tried indeed with this code, but it doesn't work with every input i call it with.

Comment: If you're insistent on using recursion then you're going to stack overflow on large inputs. If this is a homework assignment with recursion as part of the assignment, your instructor should be cognizant of this and not call it with large inputs. If this is not homework, consider dropping the recursion constraint to get a more efficient solution.

Comment: @DouglasP You can use recursion with strings too, there is no need to convert strings into lists first. To handle substrings efficiently, you only need to use the input string and two indices as parameters (start and end position)

Comment: @coredump i did the conversion cause the function is part of a program, and in that place take a list as input. I tried using only start and end position but it didin't work. I think that the function paired-b i posted is quite definitive because in most cases works, but i think that is missing some kind of additional condition.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the first `{`.  Loop from there, counting nesting levels.  When the level reaches 0, you've found the match.

```
(defun curly-positions (string)
  "Looks for the first #\{ in `string', then finds the matching #\}.
Returns these positions as two values."
  (let* ((open-position (position #\{ string :test #'char=))
         (close-position (loop :for i :upfrom (1+ open-position)
                               :for c := (char string i)
                               :for level := 1
                                 :then (case c
                                         (#\{ (1+ level))
                                         (#\} (1- level))
                                         (t level))
                               :when (zerop level)
                                 :do (return i))))
    (values open-position
            close-position))))
```